# moving on text of labelfield in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, focus, labelfield

i have large data in label field and using FOCUSABLE on it makes the whole data selected at once.Scrolling down focus goes to next LabelField.Is ther a way to move on text of  LabelField line by line 
Eg: my label field is

```
     String tenlines="line
                      line 2... 
                      line10"
     LabelField f= new LabelField(tenlines);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RichTextField

```
String tenlines="line
                      line 2... 
                      line10";

 RichTextField detailField = new RichTextField(tenlines)
```

Comment: RichTextField is automatic facusable. no need to set focusable property.

Comment: text is not fully focus but display only courser on your text.

Comment: no,neither the blue background nor the cursor comes next to Hello world.Its behaving like labelField

Comment: Add large text and check. i use same as and cursor comes to my text

Comment: focus is going on text in JDE7 based simulator but onlu after clicking the text & not scrolling and not at all on JDE 5 simulator.